# Inflection points and Hessian matrix - specific step in a proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm self-studying from a set of lecture notes about Algebraic Curves.

Let $C$ be an algebraic curve in the complex projective plane, defined by a homogeneous polynomial $P(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$. Then we say that a point $p \in C$ is an **inflection point** if there is a line $L$ with $I_p(C, L) \geq 3$. For $1 \leq i, j \leq 3$, let $P_{ij}$ be the second partial derivative of $P$ with respect to the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ coordinate, evaluated at $P$ (so for example $P_{12} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}P(p)$). Then the matrix $H = (P_{ij})$ is called the \textbf{Hessian} of $P$, evaluated at $p$.

Then a theorem states that $p$ is a point of inflection if and only if $\det H = 0$. The proof begins as follows:

> To find the multiplicity of $p$ with respect to a line we have to take the resultant of $P(x,y,z)$ and $ax + by + cz$. But this is just substituting $-(by + cz)/a$ into $P$. It is more convenient to retain the symmetry and consider the line as the set of points
> $$
> [a_0 + t\alpha_0, a_1 + t\alpha_1, a_2 + t\alpha_2]
> $$
> as $t$ varies. Then $I_p(C, L) \geq 3$ if and only if $t^3$ divides
> $$
> P(a_0 + t\alpha_0, a_1 + t\alpha_1, a_2 + t\alpha_2)
> $$

I don't see where the last statement comes from. Intersection multiplicity is defined in these notes as being the largest $k$ such that $(cy - bz)^k$ divides the resultant $\mathcal{R}_{P, L}(y, z)$. It would seem then that perhaps $t$ is intended to be some polynomial $t = t(y, z) \in \mathbb{C}[y, z]$, but this seems strange to me because $t$ is introduced as some complex parameter, whereas $y, z$ are formal indeterminates. I'm also not clear on what form such a polynomial would take.

Apologies for not having included more of my own attempts to solve this; the things I've tried are quite aimless, confusing, and very likely of no use. Any help in explaining this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hm, when I made my comments, I didn't fully work out the details. Now that I've looked at an example, I'm less convinced about the claim I'm making, although I still believe that $t$ is supposed to represent a parameter for the line. I'm going to delete my comments, lest they mislead others, and I'll think more carefully about this when I have some time.

Comment: Alright, I’ve deleted mine too. I agree $t$ should be a parameter, but since we talk about $t^3$ dividing something, we must be treating it as a polynomial, and since we actually care about polynomials in $y,z$, it seems like there must be some way of getting from one to the other. Thanks for your help!